# Loading google plus code after entire page loads

Tags: java, load, google-plus-one

I'd like to load the Google plus code after the entire page loads because it really slows load time.  I'm running Joomla, so here's exactly what I put in the php file:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="vertical-bubble" data-height="60"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function googlefunction() {

    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js'; 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</div>
```

It seems like there is probably a function that says LoadAftePage that I could wrap around it.